# tmux 1 session accessed by multiple terminals, each with a different visual state

Tags: tmux, xmonad, terminal-multiplexer, alacritty

I use a tiling window manager and someimtes have 6 or 7 shells open at once. Locally, I use tmux purely as a multiplexer because my preferred terminal does not have one (which I like). I would like each terminal that I open to access the same tmux session (which I have working), and I want to assign each terminal to a different window (1-9) in the same session. However, if I open two different terminals that share the same session, any visual state change to one will affect the other. For example, if I move one terminal to window 2 the other terminal will also move to window 2. This makes sense, but I want it to not be that way.

How can I get each terminal to share the same session but have independent visual states? If this is not possible, do you have any suggestions that are close to my intended workflow?

Comment: `tmux new-session -t …`. See [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1489266/432690).